# Angular 5 router.navigate error

Tags: router, angular5

There is an user crud page and when an new user is saved is necessary that url change with id parameter that user saved. I don't known what happen but when call this.router.navigate(['/user', user.id]) an error happens. Following the code with router and component where the error occur.

Url to create a new user
http://localhost:4200/user

Url to update user
http://localhost:4200/user/38

```
//route config
    const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: ':id', 
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: UserResolve
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: UserResolve
    }
  }
]


//component
this.router.navigate(['/user', user.id])


//error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just started to learn angular a few weeks ago so i'm just trying to help.

in your routes ts file you are linking '' to UserComponent but you are expecting the router to load the UserComponent when the path '/user' is called.

Replace the empty '' by user and tell us what's new. Thanks !